# Compare the levels of two factors

Tags: r, r-factor

Is it possible to evaluate two factors, to see whether they have the same numer of levels and if so which levels are not present in one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `factor1` and `factor2` are your two factors, just look at `levels(factor1)` and `levels(factor2)`.

Same number of levels:

```
length(levels(factor1)) == length(levels(factor2))
```

Values in one and not the other:

```
setdiff(levels(factor1), levels(factor2))
setdiff(levels(factor2), levels(factor1))
```

Comment: Thank you, it was primarily the setdiff() I was looking for :)